# problem with navigation within an xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a little problem. When I try to navigate between similar tags in my xml file it just wont jump to the next item. The text is displayed in a div (id=textb). Basically it gets all the contents from the xml file but for some reason my next() function is not working.

Javascript:

```
xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "xml/main.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
b = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("part");
var c = 0, d = 0, speed = 90, text = [];
function ticker() {
  story = b[d].getElementsByTagName("txtb")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  obj = document.getElementById("textb");
  text[c] = document.createTextNode(story.charAt(c));
  obj.appendChild(text[c]);
  c++;
  c != story.length && setTimeout(function() {
    ticker()
  }, speed)
}
function next()
{
if (d<b.length-1)
  {
  d++;
  ticker();
  }
};
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<root>
    <part>
        <txtb>
        bla1
        </txtb>
    </part>
    <part>
        <txtb>
        bla2
        </txtb>
    </part>
</root>
```

If anyone has an idea how to make it work or why it's not working it would be very nice if you could help me here.

Comment: Have you run this through Firebug or any debug tool yet? In particular, this part `c != story.length && setTimeout(function() {  ticker()}, speed)` does not seem like correct syntax, as you use the comparison operator without a comparison semantic (like `if()`).

Comment: Firebug doesn't report any problems and it even works in IE. Unfortunately just the next() function wont work. Edit: When I say it works in IE I mean even the debugger in IE doesn't report any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa). It works as cross browser wrapper to native XML Apis and might solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i'd rather not use another js library if it could be handled by just fixing some of the code I already have. Do you maybe have another suggestion? I somehow feel that there is just some minor thing I overlooked.